# CSS background solid color diagonally?

Tags: html, css, background

Is it possible in CSS to create a background to look just like this

```
.test {
width: 0;
height: 0;

border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

But I need a text to go over the diagonally. This is done by moving the border but I need it in background. 
I know I can put an image but i really need to be CSS. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can use gradients. Though browser support is not complete (the usual suspects).

**[Here's a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/yKSM6/)**.

Generated using **[ColorZilla's Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)**.